# Performing Regression Analysis using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-statistics, regression

I am trying to perform regression analysis using road accident data using ArcMap 10.1. The accident data is a point file for all accidents with information on the date the accident happened, time, male or female, weather conditions, vehicle manoeuvre etc, very detailed.

I also have a polygon data set of census tracts. My issue is that I can join the two but only get a column containing the total number of incidents (accidents) per census tract.

How can I perform regression analysis using data at 2 different scales?

The independent variables I am interested in are contained in the point data set.

Comment: Could you please provide your preferred environment for doing the regression analysis? If you could specify your preferred software with version number in the title, and in the tags it could bring more attention from specialists. Alternatively, just state in the text, you are open to work with any competent product, or list the subset you're familiar with.

Comment: I think the body of the question is the most important place for the software and version to be written.

Comment: Doing the join in the other order should solve the problem.